# Pass Integer value type to the WIX installer

Tags: iis, wix

In WIX there is a Property entity, and proeprty can be used for any "string" field/attribute of installer.

I need to configure IIS and Max Workers Count attribute, which is of Integer type.

WIX Property can't be used in this case because of compilation error.

Is there any way to configure integer field from command line with WIX?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find solution for Integer property problem.

But the problem with IIS can be solved with CustomerAction

```
<CustomAction Id="DoMagicWithIis" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="asyncNoWait" ExeCommand="appcmd <some command> [Property]" />
```